# Two conditions in a ruby block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to do something like this:

```
products = products.select { |product|
  product.quantity > 0 || (
    product.has_attribute?(:permit_negative_quantity) &&
      product.permit_negative_quantity == true)
  )
}
```

I am trying to leave only products association that has positive quantity, or, if the quantity is not positive, has the attribute `permit_negative_quantity` and it is set to`true`.

This block keeps rejecting the products with a negative quantity. Am I missing something in the syntax? Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: is `true` an actual boolean result from `#permit_negative_quantity` if it is then there is no need to check it is `true` but if this is a String or something like `"true"` then your expression is wrong. Also why are you checking to see if it has this attribute at all? Shouldn't you know? Seems like `product.quantity > 0 || product.permit_negative_quantity` should suffice.

Comment: The code you posted is not syntactically valid, it produces the error: `syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting ')'`. It seems you are missing a couple of `)`, please fix it.

Comment: But obviously still not filterating the negative quantities...

Comment: @engineersmnky : Not all product have :permit_negative_quantity column in there table, the products association is formed from objects from different classes... Don't ask me why is it so, cause i'm not the one hat designed the solution in the first place...

Comment: Whoever put -1 vote without justification, is an idiot !

Answer (score 0):

It seems higher priority of `&&` is causing this, try following:

```
products = products.select { |product| (product.quantity > 0 || (product.has_attribute?(:permit_negative_quantity) && product.permit_negative_quantity == true)) }
```

Comment: missing parens after `#has_attribute?` and at the end of the block

Comment: I fixed the parentheses issue... But still hasthe negative quantiy products being filtrated...

Answer (score 0):

Ok finally i saw what i made wrong.

It was the `:true`at the end of the condition which have to be `true`since the table column is a boolean.